# I have a problem with check sign in TCPDF

Tags: php, utf-8, tcpdf

In a protocol I have to mark several positions as checked or not checked. I tried the utf-8 characters `&check;` and `&cross;`, but also `&#10004;` and `&#10008;`, but all of show as a ? in the pdf. Other html specials as `&nbsp;` or Cyrillic characters are shown correctly.

The code is like this:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 9);
$string = '&#10004;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$string;
$string = '&check;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$string;
$string = '&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$string;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 1, 15, $pos, $string, 0, 1);
```

I also tried different fonts, like dejavu, but it's always the same. What else can I do to show the needed character?

Comment: In my opinion, the problem lies with the FreeSans font. I tried your code and switched the font to DejaVuSans, and the characters displayed correctly. `$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 9);`

Comment: You are right, it was the font. But not only. When I try my extract, its working, but not in my complete script. Then I have to search there too. But thanks for your help. At least one problem less.